# vimscript to search recursively in parents directory for the existence of a file?

Tags: vimscript

Help! I am looking for a vim script function:

The function takes "currentDirectoryPath" and "fileName"; starting from "currentDirectoryPath" it will search recursively for the existence of "fileName" in the parent directory .

Return true if "fileName" is found and stop searching.

Return false if fileName is not found when reaching root '/'.

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: What have you tried? Why is it not working? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `findfile()` for this.

```
:echo !empty(findfile(fileName, currentDirectoryPath.';'))
```

Comment: What is the ';' for after `currentDirectoryPath`?

Comment: It means search upwards (until the root directory).  See `:help file-searching`.

Answer (score 0):

Use :Ag command of the plugin FZF.vim. It is fuzzy regex search, possibly with preview.

Comment: Note that `:Ag` is a wrapper around [the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) and is better suited to search for text in the current directory rather than testing if a file exists. The appropriate fzf command would be `:Files` but it still doesn't answer OP's question who isn't looking for a fuzzy finder but for a function taking as argument a full name and returning a boolean.